# Being in Spain as an international student, with an expired TIE, will I be able to travel to Italy and back with just a return permit?

Tags: schengen, europe, italy, spain, student-visas

I am currently a Dominican student staying in Madrid, last August my visa/TIE expired, since then I've been doing all the paperwork and all I need to do to renew it, sadly it won't be done until some time in the first few months of 2020.

This December all of my family is coming to Europe for the Holidays, they're planning to stay in Madrid for a couple of days and then we plan on going to Italy for the rest of the Holidays. Knowing this I just got a permit so I can leave Spain and come back, but on said permit it says "not valid to transit Schengen States", I'm a little confused over this, what does it mean? do I need to get a different permit? Is this one enough?

Comment: In case it makes a difference, are you a citizen of Dominica, or of the Dominican Republic?  I understand they both call themselves "Dominican".

Comment: *Dominican from the Dominican Republic.

Comment: how about traveling by bus? I have the same problem and plan to travel to paris, belgium, and netherlands and go nacl to spain only for 6 days.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting constilation.

As a citizen of the **Dominican Republic** (listed in Annex I), you will require a C-Visa (Schengen Visa) issued by Italy.

Normaly as a holder of a **valid** residence permit of Spain, this would not be required.

> I just got a permit so I can leave Spain and come back, but on said permit it says "**not valid to transit Schengen States**"

- **[permiso/ autorización de regreso](https://www.abogadoextranjeriamadrid.net/en/re-entry-permits-permiso-de-regreso/)**

The only images I could find that contain the word 'Schengen' use

- **circular** and not **tránsito**

so it may mean **not valid for travel**. Most of the images found don't contain this text.

The (very small) english text of the image below says:

- *No longer valid for **roaming** the Schengen territory*

You will have to probaly go to the Italian Consulate, with all of your Spanish papers, and apply for a C-Visa. Let them then deside what to do.

As to how this issued Visa will recieve an entry/exit stamp when travelling between Spain and Italy is a good question, since this is a rather abnormal situation.

If you do **not** recieve an entry stamp in Italy, then make sure you have this Spanish document and the
flight tickets (which proves when you entered Italy) inside your passport while in Italy.

---

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, this permit I got, I can use it to travel to Italy and come back straight to Spain, this is what I've read in most websites and heard from the people I've asked around, so basically, I can go to Italy but I can't stop by any other Schengen State which wasn't part of my plans in the first place. I'm slightly concerned over this because as I'm supposed to travel next month on the 28th and I don't know if the visa process will take very long.

Comment: @KarolinaSosa I also saw a lot of those claims, but they never said if their citizenship required a visa to do so normally. I am also not sure what **para circular** means. This is only image I found with it, the others didn't have it. I would call the Italian consulate and ask.

Comment: @KarolinaSosa Just saw the (very small) english text: *No longer valid for **roaming** the Schengen territory*. I understand this as not valid for travel.

Comment: @KarolinaSosa The document in Mark's answer explicitly states that you can only cross _Spanish_ borders. You aren't allowed to enter the Schengen Area through the borders of other countries, and you aren't allowed to travel to other Schengen countries. So you take a direct flight from Madrid to the Dominican Republic and back, but you couldn't take a flight that required you to change planes in (for example) Italy, and you aren't allowed to travel to Italy. There are no systematic border checks inside Schengen, but in practice airlines will probably deny you boarding.